# Rep displaying differently for meta site in my communities

Tags: bug

I recently noticed that my rep displayed for Meta IPS is more than 3k less than my rep displayed on IPS. When I navigate to meta it shows my proper rep on the top bar, but still not in the list of my communities.

[image: Main has 3k more rep]

Comment: This bug is taking caching to the next level ....